# How to convert BPMN 2.0 xml file to XPDL format?

Tags: bpmn

I have BPMN 2.0 xml files exported from Websphere Business Modeller.
I want to convert those files into XPDL format.
Is there any converter or a conversion routine to convert BPMN 2.0 to XPDL format?